# Is that possible to calculate modular inverse of a point on elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory

Imagine that you are given a point $P$ so that $P=a\times G$. If you have no knowledge of $a$ is that possible to calculate point $I$ so that $I$ is the modular  inverse of $P$?

We know that over prime fields each member has a modular inverse, which means for $a\in \Bbb F_n$ there exists $x$ so that $ax\equiv 1\pmod n$. Now, My question is, is that possible to calculate point $I$ on the same curve as $P$ for which the equation  $I=x\times G$ holds. This is to happen with no knowledge of either $a$ or $x$.

If such algorithm exists or become discovered in future will that be considered a weakness to the security of elliptic curves?

Comment: Elliptic curve points do not have modular inverses. We can compute the additive inverse, $-P$, by negating the $Y$ coordinate of $P$ so that $-P + P$ is the identity element. It does not reveal anything about $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is a known variation of the computational Diffie-Hellman problem, called Inverse computational Diffie-Hellman (InvCDH), according to which on input $g$, $g^{x}$, it is difficult to find $g^{x^{-1}}$.

See section 2.2 at [Variations of Diffie-Hellman Problem by Bao et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.3007&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for more info and problem reduction proofs.

Comment: Will that reveal $a$ or $x$ if one can compute $I$ from $P$?

Comment: How would you compute $I$ without the knowledge of $a$ in the first place? It's even difficult to decide if $P$ and $I$ are made from a $x$ and it's inverse $x^{-1}$, respectively, in prime-order elliptic curves with large embedding degree (like secp256r1/k1), due to the Inverse decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption.